# .Net Core Rest API Request/Response best practice

Tags: rest, asp.net-core

I need some advice on how to best structure the requests and the responses for my Rest API.

I'm mostly trying to limit myself to CRUD operations on one resources and I work with one object: for example if the ressource is "book" I end up with the following actions in the controller

- [HttpPost("books")] Book Create(Book book)
- [HttpGet("books")] Book Get(int id)

This is relatively strait forward.

Now for a more complex example for the creation of a resource, I need to receive a complexe object different from my ressource and return an object containing the resource and extra data
For example for the Order resource I have a the following action in the controller:

[HttpPost("/order")] CreateOrderResponse CreateOrder(CreateOrderRequest createOrderRequest)

Here my action will use the "CreateOrderRequest" object to create to build an Order. 
Then I would like to return a "createOrderResponse" object which contains the Order but also extra information that the client needs.

I'm not sure this is the best way to go, any advice ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the following:

```
[HttpPost("/order")] CreateOrderResponse CreateOrder(CreateOrderRequest createOrderRequest)
```

And here is why:

- By this method, you are able to protect your public API from implementation details. If you expose your model to your API then you cannot make the same guarantee.
- You can also make your validations specific to the request format. In some cases, you might require one subset of your model when creating a record and another subset when editing data. This approach will allow you to handle that scenario as well.
- Security. Were you going to add that Book right to a DbContext and save it? Or attach it and update directly? Those would be potential issues from security and data quality perspectives.

But there are downsides:

- This approach is time consuming. It may not be worth the time invested if you are writing something as a learning exercise or a quick implementation. And it adds complexity. But then, you might find complexity when you realize your Book object is insufficent in all cases.
- You will feel like there is duplicate code in different places. The code may appear to be the same, but the use cases are actually different and may diverge over time. Having a Book parameter will be a liability at that point.

Comment: I'd change to "orders" instead of order, as it's a collection on which a single element it being added. Also bear in mind that from a restful purist view you should not return your newly created entity (just a 201 status code with the resource uri). But on this case I'd stick with request/response specific objects even with its (obvious) cons.